# How can I access the request object in a mongoose pre hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want the `merchantID` to be set to the logged in user in `req.user` when saving documents.

*product.model.js:*

```js
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  merchantId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "Merchant",
    required: true
    },
    ....
})

ProductSchema.pre("save", () => {
  console.log(req.user) // req object is not defined
})
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: There's no express middleware to be seen anywhere in your code.

Comment: @ChrisG I think OP wants to access req object in the mongoose pre hook. Don't think the express middleware is relevant here.

Comment: @ChrisG No, not express middleware. What I meant was mongoose middleware (pre hooks). I edited the title for clarification

Comment: You misunderstand. My guess is you need to run `ProductSchema.pre()` inside an express middleware function. How else could you use `req` in the mongoose hook? Also, are you sure that pre hook is necessary here? Couldn't you simply set the product's merchant id before saving it right in the express route?

Comment: @ChrisG oh now it makes sense, thank you. I didn't know I could use _pre_ hooks outside of a mongoose model.

Comment: It's just JS code, you can call it anywhere you like. And I still don't understand why you need a mongoose pre hook in the first place. Again, why not simply `product.merchantId = req.user.id;` then `product.save();` right in your route handler? Why do you think you need an (ever-changing) pre hook for this? This sounds more and more like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to access the request object inside a model you can use this keyword

```
UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
try {
    if (this.isNew) {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt)
        this.password = hashedPassword
    }
    next()
} catch (error) {
    next(error)

}
})
```

Here this.isNew checks whether this is a new entry it's a mongoose built method. You cannot use arrow functions since arrow functions do not allow "this" keyword

Comment: If I am not wrong, I think `this` in this case will refer to the document or object that you want to save to your DB.

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score -1):

You can use `AsyncLocalStorage` from `async_hooks` to associate state and propagate it throughout callbacks and promise chains. `AsyncLocalStorage` allows storing data throughout the lifetime of a web request or any other asynchronous duration.

Read the docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#asynchronous-context-tracking).

##### Step 1:

Create a middleware which captures your `data` from request context and place it in `AsyncLocalStorage`.

```js
const { AsyncLocalStorage } = require("async_hooks");

const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    asyncLocalStorage.run({ 
        merchant: req.user, // this is your data from request context.
     }, next);
});
```

#### Step 2:

Use `AsyncLocalStorage` instance inside middleware hook and access the stored data.

```js
ProductSchema.pre("save", () => {
  const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
  console.log(store.merchant); // from async local store you can get your data.
});
```

I have created a small git gist snippet to showcase the functionality of `async_hooks`. You can refer it [here](https://gist.github.com/s-steephan/d6cdff2168601491e5472e62463615e1#file-async-hooks-js-L18).